# Inject rendered content from several views in Pyramid into one base template

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal, template-metal

I'd like to do something like below.

I have the following routes configured:

```
config.add_route('home', '/')
config.add_route('foo', '/foo')
```

The following views:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/home.pt')
def home_view(request):
    return {...}

@view_config(route_name='foo', renderer='templates/foo.pt')
def foo_view(request):
    return {...}
```

There is a base template 'templates/base.pt':

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    Welcome ${user_id}<br>
    <a href="/foo">Foo</a><br>
    <div id="content">
        <!-- Inject rendered content here from either / or /foo --> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now in my views I'd like to inject the following content into the div with id "content":

```
<!-- templates/home.pt -->
<div id="home-content">Home content</div>

<!-- templates/foo.pt -->
<div id="foo-content">Foo content</div>
```

How would I go about changing **home_view** and **foo_view** above so that they can inject their own templates (home.pt, foo.pt) into base.pt? Somehow I also need to transfer data such as **${user_id}** into base.pt as well. I was playing around with the **wrapper** argument when defining my views, but couldn't figure out how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this in several ways (see e.g. [Using ZPT Macros in Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/templates.html#using-zpt-macros-in-pyramid) or [Chameleon documentation introduction](http://chameleon.repoze.org/docs/latest/#introduction)).

In your simple case, I think this is the fastest way: first, change your `base.pt` file to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
      xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal">
<head></head>
<body>
    Welcome ${user_id}<br>
    <a href="/foo">Foo</a><br>
    <div id="content">
        <tal:block metal:define-slot="content">
        </tal:block>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This defines a `content` slot of the Chameleon macro.

Your `foo.pt` could look like this:

```
<metal:main
    xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
    xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
    use-macro="load: base.pt">
    <tal:block metal:fill-slot="content">
        <div id="foo-content">Foo content</div>
    </tal:block>
</metal:main>
```

Note the `use-macro="load: base.pt` line. `home.pt` should follow the same pattern. `user_id` and other template variables are available to the macro, so, for example, if you set `user_id` to `USER`, `/foo` will render:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
    Welcome USER<br>
    <a href="/foo">Foo</a><br>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="foo-content">Foo content</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks more or less exacly what I want. I guess the different view methods would have to get a base-dict from some common method and add extra data to it before returning? (Since all templates using base.pt need to have the same basic data that base.pt will render, in this example only user_id but for my real base.pt I have more data that is common)

Comment: Always nice to be able to cash in from the community :) Thanks!